# SpeechRecognizer CALLING_PACKAGE

Tags: android

I develop a app use RecognitionService ,how can know the CALLING_PACKAGE from the RecognizerIntent or callback
`mSpeech.setRecognitionListener(mRecognitionListener);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("partial_result", true);
        mSpeech.startListening(intent);`

Comment: what exactly do you mean? the calling package is your package name.

Comment: i'm sorry my english is not good ,i just develop a speechservice implements the RecognitionService , any speech apps in the device call the speechservice just send intent , I just want know  which one call the service when my speech service receive the intent. the intent doesn't contain the packagename.`protected void onStartListening(Intent recognizerIntent, Callback listener)`

Comment: Are you develop a speech recognizer engine?

Comment: yes,a speech recognizer engine use my company service

Comment: I think an activity calling createSpeechRecognizer has to pass in the package name in the recognizer intent. At least that what is required for use of google engine. I have to pass in mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName()); So I think you can get it by calling intent.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE)

Comment: Thank you ,i have try this method,it correctly.but you know that some apps do not pass  the packagename into the intent, I think two ways maybe solve this question,one is find the package's pid by the intent,the other one is can i use the RecognitionService.Callback find the user.

Comment: You can required the calling activity to pass in the package name. That what google does, if the intent has no EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE then there speech recognizer does not work and there is no error either. I have to play around for a while before I stumble upon it.